# Fetch portainer templates blocked by unbound

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, portainer, unbound, pihole

I'm using portainer to manage my docker containers on my raspberry pi.

I have also setup pi-hole and unbound.

When I try to fetch portainer templates, I get a 500: `Unable to retrieve templates via the network`
with details:

> Get "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/SelfhostedPro/selfhosted_templates/portainer-2.0/Template/template.json": dial tcp: lookup raw.githubusercontent.com on 127.0.0.11:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:59111-\u003e127.0.0.11:53: i/o timeout

I already found out that it has something to do with the unbound / pihole installation. But I don't really know what to do now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this question was ever answered, but I have somewhat of an answer.

I have a Pi3b running Portainer with several containers from pi-hosted. One of them is Pihole-Unbound. Although it's configured to the best of my capabilities, at one point in time I was also unable to update my templates. Since I knew it worked when I originally installed and configured Pihole-Unbound, I was able to determine what changed. On the LAN setup page of my router, after configuring Unbound I removed the DNS entries for OpenDNS and entered my Unbound IP. Once I added a secondary DNS, the Portainer template updates worked.

With that knowledge I decided I could add a custom DNS entry just for Portainer. I used the --DNS option. Here's my updated command line for starting Portainer:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -p 9443:9443 --name=portainer --restart=always --dns=208.67.222.222 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer-ce:latest
```